# R Shiny: How to subset and then sort a data frame?

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to Shiny. I was trying to subset a data frame and the data frame, but encountered an error message:

*"Can't access reactive value 'xx' outside of reactive consumer."*

Could anybody tell me why?

The design idea is to (1) let the users to select the subgroup that they'd like to look into, which I tried to accomplish using the reactiveValues() command but failed, and then (2), an delayed action, which is within that subgroup, sort the data based on a key variable. Below are the codes, and I appreciate your help:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
data(iris)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    title = "Test",

    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "Tab 3, subset and then sort",
        sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("xx", "species:", choices = unique(iris$Species), selected = "setosa"),
            actionButton("click", "sort")
          ),

          mainPanel(
            tableOutput("table3")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(

    #### This line caused a problem whenever I added %>% dplyr::filter ####
    df3 = iris %>% dplyr::filter(Species == !!input$xx)
  )

  observeEvent(input$click, {
    rv$df3 <- rv$df3[order(rv$df3$Sepal.Length), ]
  })

  output$table3 <- renderTable({
    rv$df3
  })
}

# Run the application
app <- shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp(app)
```

Comment: Double-bang `!!` is relevant for non-standard evaluation in `rlang` and `tidyeval` and such. I don't think this is that. Also, you're using `reactiveValues` incorrectly, you should just be using `reactive` or `eventReactive`. Try `rv <- reactive({ dplyr::filter(iris, Species == $input$xx) ])`, and then all other references to `rv` need to be `rv()` (as in `rv()$df3`).

Answer (score 0):

1. `reactiveValues` should be used like a list of values that are updated/evaluated within `reactive`/`observe` blocks. It's being used incorrectly here, I think you should be using `reactive` or `eventReactive`.
2. Double-bang `!!` is relevant for NSE (non-standard evaluation) within `rlang` (and much of the tidyverse), but that's not what you're doing here. In your case, `input$xx` is `character`, in which case you can simply compare to it directly, ala `Species == input$xx`.
3. Sometimes, depending on the startup of an app, the reactive is triggered before the input has a valid value, instead it'll be `NULL`. This causes an error and glitches in the shiny interface, and can be avoided by the use if `req`.
4. Unfortunately, you can't resort a `reactive` data block outside of it.

Here's one alternative:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  rv_unsorted <- reactive({
    req(input$xx)
    dplyr::filter(iris, Species == input$xx)
  })
  rv_sorted <- reactive({
    req(input$click)
    dplyr::arrange(isolate(rv_unsorted()), Sepal.Length)
  })
  output$table3 <- renderTable({
    rv_sorted()
  })
}
```

---

Another method, which is less efficient (more greedy, less lazy),

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveVal(iris)
  observeEvent(input$xx, {
    rv( dplyr::filter(iris, Species == input$xx) )
  })
  observeEvent(input$click, {
    rv( dplyr::arrange(rv(), Sepal.Length) )
  })
  output$table3 <- renderTable({
    rv()
  })
}
```

This may seem more straight-forward logically, but it will do more work than will technically be necessary. (`observe` blocks are greedy, firing as quickly as possible, even if their work is not used/noticed. `reactive` blocks are lazy in that they will never fire unless something uses/needs them.)

**Edit**: I corrected the previous behavior, which was:

1. Load `iris`, have all species present, store in `rv()`.
2. Immediately filter, showing just `setosa`, store in `rv()`.
3. Display in the table.
4. Change selector to a new species.
5. Filter the contents of `rv()` so that only the new species are in the frame. *Unfortunately*, since the contents of `rv()` were *just* `setosa`, this next filtering removed all rows.

The means that the current `observe`-sequence (as greedy and inefficient as it may be) must start with a fresh frame at some point, so I changed the `input$xx` observe block to always start from `iris`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Somehow, using the second method, the table will be rendered blank, if I select a species other than the default one from the drop-down menu of the app. Looks like the reactivity was broken somewhere--- not sure if it was a problem on my end only, but would you care to look again method 2 and see where the reactivity might be broken?

Comment: Ah, yes, that's my mistake. That's now another reason that I don't like that approach. The reason? `rv()` starts with the full frame, then it should immediately remove all but `setosa`. When you change the selector, it then removes everything except the new species ... but since only `setosa` was in there, it reduced to 0 rows. See my edit.

Comment: Fantastic - what you said makes a lot sense - thanks again. I have one more question about the first method if you don't mind. The app will display the sorted results only (only `rv_sorted()` is inside `renderTable()`). How do I design the server part, if I'd like the app to show the unsorted table first, and let the users to sort the values if they like to, by clicking the action button? This is closer to the original idea, and more aligned with method 2, but method 2, as you pointed out, has its own problem.

Comment: I think the way that you want it -- an `actionButton` has the side-effect of sorting the data -- then you need something like `reactiveValues` in the second code block. If you want it optionally sorted and still very reactive, then change your `actionButton` to a `checkboxInput` and condition sorting on that within a single `reactive` (first code block is appropriate for this).